# Solrj addfilterquery adding "+" sign to replace whitespace in range query

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using SolrJ to make queries to a Solr collection. However when I do add a filter query "+" signs are being added by the addfilterquery function, and replace the single whitespace in my query. This then means the query is invalid and I get zero results ...

```
solrQuery.setQuery("*:*");

solrQuery.addFilterQuery("eligibility.minimum_age_value:[0 TO 99]");
```

results in

```
"q=*:*&fq=eligibility.minimum_age_value:[0+TO+99]"
```

How can I stop the `"+"` signs replacing the single whitespace?

Using `Solrj 8.5.0` in Maven

Comment: Why would you want to stop that? Spaces are escaped as `+` in an URL, so that they're handled as they should on the other side of the request. However; why do you have a space after the field name? `eligibility.minimum_age_value:[0 TO 99]` - my guess is that that space effectively makes it different terms, and that's why you're not getting any results.

Comment: You are totally correct, the + sign was not the issue. I had some other error in my code that was the real reason!